# null checking with "and or" syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, null

In a jQuery [special events article](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/4/jquery-edge-new-special-event-hooks) I found syntax that I haven't seen before:

```
var threshold = data && data.threshold || 1
```

I have seen before the following:

```
var threshold = data.threshold || 1
```

Which to the best of my knowledge means: set to `data.threshold` or if its value is `null` then set to `1`. Can I please get explanation on first syntax?

Comment: [MDN Logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) These sorts of operators are basic language features, and are well documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&&` has higher associativity than `||`, so the first example actually means:

```
var threshold = (data && data.threshold) || 1;
```

You can read this as "set `threshold` to `data.threshold` only if `data` and `data.threshold` have truthy values, otherwise set it to 1."  If `data` was null/undefined/etc and the code tried accessing `data.threshold` without first checking `data`, this would result in an exception.  This syntax allows for checking *both* at once, in a compact way.

Answer (score 3):

In english it means

if data is truthy
 **AND** (the `&&` symbol)
`data.threshold` is truthy, set `threshold` to `data.threshold`,
**OR** (else)
set `threshold` to 1.

truthy means not null, not undefined, and not 0 (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

`&&` returns the left hand side if the left hand side evaluates as false. Otherwise it returns the right hand side.

So if `data` is false, it returns `date`, so the `||` then passes `1` in.

If `data` is not false, but `data.threshold` is, it also evaluates as false so the `||` still passes `1` in.

If `data.threshold` is true, then `||` passes the left hand side, which is `data.threshold`